# How compile code C xen in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, parallel-processing, xen

### I have problem in compile code C xen :-(

I change code C program and insert **#include stdio** to program for open/close file. I use of command "make" for compile code C in xen But I meet to error:

```
../../../include/stdio.h:28:23 fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
```

I insert to command "make" -I But again repeat error !

How compile code C xen in linux.

[image: code compiling xen to command "make xen -I /usr/include" and product error of command]

it's show The general part of the code has been changed to i added and cause error because ago this code not error but i don't really why i can't add **#include stdio.h** to code for read function fputc and...?!

```
#include <stdio.h> // i add
#include <xen/config.h>
#include <xen/init.h>
#include <xen/lib.h>
#include <xen/sched.h>
#include <xen/domain.h>
#include <xen/delay.h>
#include <xen/event.h>
#include <xen/time.h>
#include <xen/perfc.h>
#include <xen/sched-if.h>
#include <xen/softirq.h>
#include <asm/atomic.h>
#include <xen/errno.h>
#include <xen/keyhandler.h>


struct csched_dom *sdom;

xc_shadow_op_stats_t stats;
FILE *out;
    if(iter>=2) {       
    out = fopen("/test.dat", "w");
    fputc(sdom->weight , out);
    fclose(out);

   }
else
   {
    sdom->weight = CSCHED_DEFAULT_WEIGHT;

    out = fopen("/test.txt", "w");
    fputc(sdom->weight , out);
    fclose(out);        
   }
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: And "show your code" means copying the text into your question and properly formatting it, not simply posting a screenshot or image.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of text terminals, it's a waste of resources.

Comment: Xen is a bare metal hypervisor. It sits between your hardware and your OS. Tere are no files at that level, so no stdio.h.

Comment: Please provide your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

`stdio` is not available in the environment the Xen hypervisor runs in. It doesn't deal with files at all - they simply don't exist at the level it's working at.

You can use the `printk()` function to display messages to the Xen console. However, if this is news to you, you're probably in over your head - you may be more at ease working with something else. (Try working with the Linux kernel first, perhaps.)